# Manera correcta de enviar un parametro vacio

Tags: html

Tengo este codigo

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Top</title>
        </head>
        <frameset rows="70,*,15" border="0">
            <frame src="test.asp" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" name="criterios">
            <frame src="reporte.asp?suc=Todas&TopReg=25&Emisora=''" name="reporte">
        </frameset>
        <noframes>
        </noframes>
    </html>
```

Quiero enviar el parametro Emisora como vacio, saben si esta es la manera correcta ?

Answer (score 0):

Así es suficiente:

```
<frame src="reporte.asp?suc=Todas&TopReg=25&Emisora=" name="reporte">
```